# IIS 10 + MediaWiki: Wrong encoding for short URLs

Tags: mediawiki, urlencode

I am running MediaWiki on Windows Server 2016 (language set to Korean) in a local network. I have followed [the MediaWiki manual for enabling short URLs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/IIS8.5), and the result was below:

A. `대문`¹ becomes `´ë¹®` and inaccessible via its short URL.

B. `媛곴컖` becomes `각각`.² A link to `媛곴컖` points to `http://192.168.0.123/wiki/媛곴컖` (or `http://192.168.0.123/wiki/%E5%AA%9B%EA%B3%B4%EC%BB%96`) and shows the content of page `각각` when clicked.

In both cases, their full URLs (like `http://192.168.0.123/w/index.php?title=%EB%8C%80%EB%AC%B8`) work 99%³ perfectly.

With some investigations, I found there are some encoding issues.

```
(A)
EB 8C 80 EB AC B8
↓ Decoded with UTF-8
대문
↓ Encoded with EUC-KR
B4 EB B9 AE
↓ Decoded with Latin-1
´ë¹®

(B)
E5 AA 9B EA B3 B4 EC BB 96
↓ Decoded with UTF-8
媛곴컖
↓ Encoded with EUC-KR
EA B0 81 EA B0 81
↓ Decoded with UTF-8
각각
```

It seems that EUC-KR is involved in some point of the URL encoding/decoding process, but I could not find the certain setting anywhere in IIS or MediaWiki settings.

---

¹ Korean word for "Main Page"

² `媛곴컖` is mojibake of `각각`, which means "each" in Korean. But the meaning itself is not meaningful in this context.

³ The remaining 1% is of VisualEditor replacing category links to their full URLs, e.g. `Category:Foo` to `Category:index.php?title=Foo`.

Comment: Unless you have clear evidence that those links were generated by IIS/Windows, those are not the tags you should use. If in `web.config` you have specific settings (like rewriting rules), then they should be added as part of the question.